# Are there vaccines that are safe to use in adults, but harmful in children?

Tags: vaccination

I've recently read an article mentioning how [vaccine companies are enrolling children](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-01-19/kids-sign-up-for-vaccine-trials-in-next-step-to-conquer-covid) to test if their vaccines work on kids too. But is this just a theoretical concern or is there historical precedent for such trials to take place? To clarify, I'm looking for examples of a vaccine that:

1. Was approved to be used for adults
2. Did not have significant side effects in adults
3. Had significant side effects in children, possibly resulting in lack of approval for child vaccinations
4. "Children" here is defined as humans over the age of 6, as no studies are currently recruiting kids younger than that

If anything, the vaccines that we get these days are usually given at a young age rather than during adulthood so I'd expect the opposite issue to be more common.

Comment: +1 but even if there aren't such prior vaccine incidents (in children only) there are probably wider regulatory precautions against medicines not being approved in children without prior trials in that age group in particular.

Comment: I'd be surprised if one was found to be unsafe but I wouldn't be surprised if one was found to be ineffective.

Comment: @CareyGregory https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm5619a4.htm

Comment: @CodeCamper The child wasn't given a vaccine and it was contraindicated for the father.

Comment: @CareyGregory If second hand vaccine exposure was unsafe for the child surely first hand exposure would be at least equally as unsafe? Also there seems to be a debate whether having someone under 12 months old in the house is a contraindication https://www.health.ny.gov/publications/7004/

Comment: @CodeCamper, the key element in that case wasn't the "child" bit, it was the "eczema" bit.  Note that the mother, who presumably isn't a child, *also* got eczema vaccinatum.

Comment: @Mark Yes, but the child's symptoms were more severe and took longer to recover and required more intervention. But I guess this question is ignoring children under 7 years old and defining children as 7 to 17?